# Clean up deprecated and unused packages in React project with yarn

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

Just ran `yarn upgrade` on my project and saw that a bunch of older packages are deprecated and not supported anymore. How can I remove those deprecated and unused packages in my React project using yarn? I was searching and found 2 commands, but unsure what is the right approach:

- `yarn autoremove` - remove unused packages (command didn't work for me, suggested by ChatGPT)
- `yarn autoclean --force` - haven't tried since there is a forced removal, but this command is meant to clean up unnecessary files

What are some best practices around this?